# Calculating a line integral using Stokes Theorem (Finding a normal vector)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Solve the line integral, where you have a smooth vector field
$F= \{x+2y,2z+2x,z+y\}$ and where the curve $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$ and the plane $y=z$

**My attempt:**

$$\operatorname{curl} F = (-1,0,0)$$

I know how to calculate the majority of things for this question, however I don't know which surface to use and also how would I calculate the normal vector for a particular surface?

Thank you

Comment: Is the line integral $\displaystyle \oint_C F\cdot dr\ $? $\qquad$

Comment: I believe it is, yes and we are asked to specifically use the double integral form of stokes theorem

Comment: Do you know what $C$ looks like?

Comment: Hint: a normal to your surface is also going to be normal to the plane $y=z$.

Comment: the plane intersects the cylinder in an ellipse,which may be taken to be $S$. Since $z=y$ the normal can be calculated easily. When subbing into Stokes you may want to paramterize the surface using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), 
$$
\oint_C F \cdot dr = \iint_S \operatorname{curl} F \cdot n\; dS  
$$
As you say $\operatorname{curl} F=(-1,0,0)$ and $n$ is a unit normal vector of the $y=z$ plane pointing towards the top:
$$
n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,-1,1)
$$
It follows that 
$$
\iint_S \operatorname{curl} F \cdot n\; dS = \iint_S 0 \;dS=0
$$

Comment: I put \operatorname{curl} where appropriate and deleted the manually added spacing, leaving that to the software. $\qquad$